# Accessing an image in CSS after activating assets in Twig and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to create my own template with Symfony 2, but the problem is with the CSS when I write `backround:url('images/img.png')` the image doesn't show, but in my `base.html.twig` this URL works very well `"{{ asset('images/templatemo_ads.jpg ') }}"`.

I have put my CSS and images folders into `web` folder because I will use them in other bundles and I use this command to activate assets PHP `app/console assets:install web`.

Comment: where is located your css file vs images ? `web/style.css` and `web/images/templatemo_ads.jpg` ? try this : `url("../images/templatemo_ads.jpg")`

Comment: You may want to check the cssrewrite filter in Sf.

Comment: mickdev yes I put them in those folders but  the url you gave me doesn't work  either :(

Comment: Maerlyn5 cssrewrite is activated in config.php that's it ??

Answer (score 0):

`background:url()` is conflict the default function of `url()` in the `symfony/asset` bundle.

**Try inline js:**

```
$('.test').css("background", "url({{ asset('images/templatemo_ads.jpg ') }}) no-repeat");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "./" or "../" at the start of the CSS url.

When you use it, it says to the file system to look into the file system from the CSS file, when you don't you are setting a path to add after the current URL to look for the file there (associated with symfony routing, it might work on the homepage if it's the naked domain name, but that's it.)

You should avoid using JS on file sourcing, since people might block it.